# How to use Python f-strings with pandas sql insert

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I am using:

```
     from pandas.io import sql
     ...           
                for sql_data in data_tuple:
                    sql_insert = f"INSERT INTO \"{table}\" VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
                    sql.execute(sql_insert, engine, params=[sql_data])
```

Instead of %s I tried using {}, but this isn't allowed with f-strings. Is there any better way to do it without %s with f-strings?

EDIT: the code works fine, sql_data consists of 6 values, which are passed as 6 %s and data is written to the database. What I wanted is to somehow use the code without %s which I understand is an old way in Python for string formatting?

Comment: FWIW, that `params=[sql_data]` looks weird, but what is the problem with your code?

Comment: I don't think you need `%s` in your f-string. It would go like `f"INSERT INTO \"{table}\" VALUES ({value1}, {value2}, {value3}, {value4}, {value5}, {value6})"`.

Comment: The `%s` aren't part of Python's string formatting, though they look similar. They are interpreted solely by `sql.execute`. One problem is that your insert statement expects 6 arguments, but you are only providing one. If `sql_data` is already a list of the 6 values you need, then you want `params=sql_data`.

Comment: @QuangHoang No, no, no. The `%s` is part of the format expected by `sql.execute`, not part of Python's string formatting.

Comment: To be clear, `f"INSERT INTO \"{table}\" ...` is not safe, but many SQL libraries don't have a better alternative.

Comment: @chepner That's what I'm saying: IMHO, better format on Python side than in `sql`.

Comment: @Quang but ONLY for the table name, not for the data thats better being passed via parametrized query which needs the `%s`.

Comment: No, it is far *worse* to format on the Python side; that's why the `execute` method does its own formatting in the first place.

Comment: `psycopg2`, for example, provides extensions for safely parameterizing the table name without Python string formatting.

Comment: @chepner - got it, didn't know that this is part of sql.execute and not Python's string formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@chepner explained in comments:

> The `%s` aren't part of Python's string formatting, though they look similar. They are interpreted solely by `sql.execute`.